# Change two pieces of state inside a ternary operator *React*

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, conditional-operator, use-state

Is it suitable to change two pieces of state in a ternary operator or is this something that is best to do using an if-else statement?

Everything I try seems to run into issues.

Examples of what I have tried are shown below.

```
x === y ? () => {setRating(10); setRank(1)} : console.log("Not found")
```

```js
x === y ? setRating(10); setRank(1) : console.log("Not found")
```

What is the difference between this and the following if-else statement?

```
if (x === y) {
    setRating(10);
    setRank(1);
} else {
    console.log("Not found")
}
```

Comment: For readability purposes, I would recommend you to use an `if` statement. Ternary operators are commonly used for simple `if-else` operations.

Comment: It needs to be a single *expression*. You could use the *comma operator*, but writing it as a standard if statement might be more readable.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That just would make your code unreadable... Use an if statement.

Comment: the simple rule is, if you do not use the result of a conditional operator, then don't use it.

Comment: You should just use if statements, unless you really want to put it into 1 line

Answer (score 4):

Separate the expressions with the comma operator, and wrap them with parentheses.

```js
const fn = x => x ? (console.log('true'), console.log('again')) : console.log('false')

fn(true)
```

However, you should prefer an if/else statement for readability purposes:

```js
const fn = x => {
  if(x) {
    console.log('true');
    console.log('again');
  } else {
    console.log('false');
  }
}

fn(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
const setData = (index,average)=>{
 setRating(average);
 setRank(index) 
}
```

and change your ternary operator as

```
place.name.toUpperCase() === doc.data().place ?setData(index,doc.data().average):console.log("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the call in self executing  arrow function but it's not something I would recommend doing as it isn't a good practice.

Creating a third function that calls the two function is the recommended way of doing it.

```
place.name.toUpperCase() === doc.data().place ? (() => 
    setRating(doc.data().average);
    setRank(index))() 
    : console.log("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the answer of Ori Dori, However  another approach could be separating the two functions in truth block to another function like this:

```
place.name.toUpperCase() === doc.data().place ?
    onFound() : console.log("Not found");


function onFound() {
    setRating(doc.data().average);
    setRank(index) 
}
```